# Replacing in array, one value with a key

Tags: php

I have a problem with the conversion of the array.
I have this arrays:

```
 Array
  (
   [0] => Array
    (
        [x] => 1291
        [y] => 32
        [z] => 1142
        [number] => 51
    )

   [1] => Array
    (
        [x] => 1415
        [y] => 32
        [z] => 1142
        [number] => 22
    )
)
```

How to make from this, the arrays

```
 Array
  (
   [51] => Array
    (
        [x] => 1291
        [y] => 32
        [z] => 1142
    )

   [22] => Array
    (
        [x] => 1415
        [y] => 32
        [z] => 1142
    )

)
```

[number] does not have to be removed from the array. It's important, to become the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$numbers = array();
//Get the list of 'number' keys and unset them (optional)
foreach ($array as &$values) {
   $numbers[] = $values['number'];
   unset($values['number']);
}
//create a new array with numbers as keys and the original array as values
//You could also overwrite the original array, which will save some memory
$result = array_combine($numbers, $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new array

```
$newarray = array();
foreach($yourarray as $k=>$v) {
    $newarray[$v['number']] = $v
}

print_r($newarray);
```

Comment: you did not unset "number" key

Comment: it is what he wants : look at the result array.

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop over your original array would fix this:

```
$new = array();

foreach($old as $item) {
    $key = $item['number'];
    $new[$key] = $item;
}

var_dump($new);
```

Comment: you did not unset "number" key.

Comment: @artragis I know. That was not a requirement, was it?

Comment: it was : look at the result array.

Comment: @artragis No, the point was to create a new where each key was taken from number.

Answer (score 1):

No need to create a new array as many of the other answers suggest, this can be done in-place.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
    $array[$value["number"]] = $array[$key];

    // remove number attribute (optional)
    unset($array[$value["number"]]["number"]);

    // remove array @ original key
    unset($array[$key]);
}
```